# Ubuntu Mysql suddenly locked me out

Tags: mysql

I'm experiencing a very weird problem here. I was using a mysql database for developing a rails app and everything was fine. Then I rebooted the computer (Ubuntu 13.10) and found myself locked out of the database with this message:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Both the rails app and the command line give me this message. I've followed the instructions to reset the mysql root password but to no avail -- every time I stop mysqld (whether via kill, /etc/init.d/, or any other recommended method the process disappears for about 2 seconds only to reappear with a new pid. It's almost as if a virus has taken over (could that be??).

Anyway I am hermetically sealed out of my mysql server. Any ideas on what happened and what I could do about it?

EDIT:  I know how to log into mysql via command line w/ a password.  The problem is that I set no password during install and something set one for me, and I have no clue what it is.

Comment: This was not my issue.  I know how to access mysql from the command line using a password.  The problem is that I didn't set a root password at all during install and then it set one for me, or so it seems.  Plus I can't stop mysqld so I cant even reset the root password

Comment: I just re-read my question and I see where the confusion comes in.  I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. I'll edit the question.